# O que é o DIANA?

Tags: oracle, terminologia

Estive com um problema de banco de dados relacionado ao tamanho de um objeto, que retornava o seguinte erro:

> pls-00123 programa grande demais (diana nodes)

O problema eu entendi e sei o que pode ser feito, porém gostaria de compreender um pouco mais sobre esse tal de `DIANA` ( **Descriptive Intermediate Attributed Notation for Ada**).

- Pra que serve este tal de DIANA?
- De que maneira esses Nós(Diana Nodes) se relacionam com um banco?
- O que isso tem haver com espaço no caso do Oracle( o erro descrito tem haver com o tamanho do objeto, no caso uma trigger muito grande)?
- Os objetos de banco que eu crio sempre estarão ligados a um nó DIANA?

  Referência utilizada para resolver o erro :
  [PL/SQL Program Limits](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/limits.htm)

**Nota:** Na referência também há um breve explicação do mesmo, porém, achei meio confuso. Gostaria de uma resposta melhor e em português.

Answer (score 2):

PL/SQL é baseado na linguagem de programação Ada. O PL/SQL usa uma variante da Notação Atribuída Intermediária Descritiva para Ada (DIANA), uma linguagem intermediária estruturada em árvore. É definido usando uma meta-notação chamada Interface Definition Language (IDL). O DIANA é usado internamente por compiladores e outras ferramentas.

No momento da compilação, o texto de origem PL/SQL é convertido em código do sistema. O DIANA e o código do sistema para um subprograma ou pacote são armazenados no banco de dados. No tempo de execução, eles são carregados no conjunto de memórias compartilhadas. **O DIANA é usado para compilar subprogramas dependentes; o código do sistema simplesmente é executado.**

No conjunto de memórias compartilhadas, uma especificação de pacote, especificação ADT, subprograma independente ou bloco anônimo é limitada a 67108864 (2 ** 26) **nós DIANA que correspondem a tokens como identificadores, palavras-chave, operadores e assim por diante.** Isso permite ~ 6.000.000 de linhas de código, a menos que você exceda os limites impostos pelo compilador PL/SQL, alguns dos quais são fornecidos na Tabela C-1 .

Em resumo, como funciona:

1) No momento da compilação, o código-fonte PL / SQL é convertido em código do sistema e gera o DIANA correspondente.

2) O DIANA e o código do sistema para um subprograma ou pacote são armazenados no banco de dados.

3) No tempo de execução, eles são carregados no conjunto de memórias compartilhadas.

4) O DIANA é usado para compilar subprogramas dependentes; mais especificamente, para verificar / validar se o subprograma ainda é válido. isso é necessário porque, como sabemos que um subprograma pode usar objetos de banco de dados, como Tabelas, Exibições, Sinônimos ou outros procs armazenados. Pode ser possível que os objetos tenham sido alterados / removidos / descartados na próxima vez que você executar o programa. Por exemplo: alguém pode ter descartado a tabela, a procedure ou função armazenada pode ter mudado.

5) Depois que a validação é feita usando o DIANA, o código do sistema simplesmente é executado.

Infelizmente, você não pode estimar o número de nós DIANA a partir do tamanho analisado. Duas unidades de programa com o mesmo tamanho analisado podem exigir nós DIANA 1500 e 2000, respectivamente, porque, por exemplo, a segunda unidade contém instruções SQL mais complexas.

Mais informações sobre os cálculos dos nós da DIANA, leia este livro **"Ada-Europe '93: 12ª Conferência Internacional Ada-Europe", Ada Sans Frontieres ", Paris, França, de 14 a 18 de junho de 1993. Proceedings"**

A seguinte nota de suporte aborda bem este tópico ...

```
Article-ID:         <Note:62603.1>
Folder:             PLSQL
Topic:              General Information Articles
Title:              'PLS-123 Program too Large' - Size Limitations on PLSQL 
                    Packages
Document-Type:      BULLETIN
Impact:             MEDIUM
Skill-Level:        NOVICE
Server-Version:     07 to 08
Updated-Date:       13-JUN-2000 17:41:01
References:
```

### Visão geral

Este artigo contém informações sobre limitações de tamanho de pacote PL / SQL . Quando os limites são atingidos, você recebe o seguinte erro:

```
Programa PLS-123
```

### Limitações de tamanho muito grandes nos pacotes PL / SQL

Nas versões anteriores à 8.1.3, grandes programas resultaram no PLS- Erro 123. Isso ocorreu devido a limites genuínos no compilador; não como resultado de um bug.

Ao compilar uma unidade PL / SQL, o compilador cria uma árvore de análise. O tamanho máximo de uma unidade PL / SQL é determinado pelo tamanho da árvore de análise. Existe um número máximo de nós diana nessa árvore.

Até 7,3, era possível ter 2 ** 14 (16K) nós dianas e de 8.0 a 8.1.3, 2 ** 15 (32K) nós diana eram permitidos. Com a 8.1.3, esse limite foi relaxado, para que agora você possa ter 2 ** 26 (ou seja, 64M) nós diana nessa árvore para corpos de tipo e pacote.

### Limites do código fonte

Embora não haja uma maneira fácil de converter os limites em termos de linhas de código fonte, foi nossa observação que houve aproximadamente 5 a 10 nós por linha de código fonte. Antes da 8.1.3, o compilador podia compilar de maneira limpa até cerca de 3.000 linhas de código.

A partir do 8.1.3, o limite foi reduzido para package bodies e type bodies que agora podem ter aproximadamente até 6.000.000 de linhas de código. Como já citado.

Notas: Esse novo limite se aplica apenas a package bodies e type bodies. Além disso, agora você pode começar a atingir outros limites do compilador antes de atingir esse limite específico.

Em termos de tamanho do código-fonte, suponha que os tokens (identificadores, operadores, funções etc.) tenham, em média, quatro caracteres. Em seguida, o máximo seria:

Até 7,3: 4 * (2 ** 14) = 64K

De 8.0 a 8.1.3: 4 * (2 ** 15) = 128K

Com 8.1.3: 4 * (2 ** 25) = 256M

Esta é uma estimativa aproximada. Se o seu código tiver muitos espaços, identificadores longos, etc., você poderá acabar com um código-fonte maior que isso. Você também pode acabar com um código-fonte menor que isso, se seus fontes usarem identificadores muito curtos, etc.

Observe que isso é por unidade de programa, portanto é mais provável que os package bodies encontrem esse limite.

Como verificar o tamanho atual de um pacote

---

Para verificar o tamanho de um pacote, o número relacionado mais próximo que você pode usar é `PARSED_SIZE` na visualização do dicionário de dados `USER_OBJECT_SIZE`. Este valor fornece o tamanho do DIANA em bytes, conforme armazenado nas tabelas `SYS.IDL_xxx$`, e NÃO é o tamanho do conjunto compartilhado.

O tamanho da parte DIANA do código PL / SQL (usado durante a compilação) é MUITO maior no pool compartilhado do que na tabela do sistema.

Por exemplo, você pode começar a ter problemas com um limite de 64K quando o `PARSED_SIZE` em `USER_OBJECT_SIZE` não for superior a 50K.

Para um pacote, o tamanho ou tamanho analisado (size e parsed size) do DIANA faz sentido apenas para todo o objeto, não separadamente para a especificação e o corpo.

Se você selecionar `parsed_size` para um pacote, receberá tamanhos de código e origem separados para a especificação e o corpo, mas apenas um tamanho analisado significativo para todo o objeto que é gerado na linha para a especificação do pacote. Um 0 é emitido para o `parsed_size` na linha do corpo do pacote.

O exemplo a seguir demonstra esse comportamento:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE example AS
PROCEDURE dummy1;
END example;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY example AS
PROCEDURE dummy1 IS
BEGIN
NULL;
END;
END;
/

SQL> start t1.sql;

Package created.


Package body created.

SQL> select parsed_size from user_object_size where name='EXAMPLE';


PARSED_SIZE
-----------
185
0


SQL> select * from user_object_size where name='EXAMPLE';

.....
```

O Oracle armazena o DIANA e o MCODE no banco de dados. MCODE é o código real que é executado, enquanto o DIANA para uma determinada unidade de biblioteca X contém informações necessárias para compilar procedimentos usando a unidade de biblioteca X.

A seguir, há várias notas:

a) O DIANA é representado no IDL. A versão linear do IDL é armazenada no disco. A árvore de análise real é construída e armazenada no conjunto compartilhado. É por isso que o tamanho do DIANA no pool compartilhado geralmente é maior que no disco.

b) O DIANA para procedimentos chamados é necessário no pool compartilhado somente quando você cria procedimentos. Nos sistemas de produção, não há necessidade do DIANA no conjunto compartilhado (mas apenas no MCODE).

c) A partir do release 7.2, o DIANA para package bodies é descartado, não utilizado e não armazenado no banco de dados. É por isso que o `PARSED_SIZE` (tamanho da DIANA) dos `PACKAGE BODIES` é 0.

> Portanto, procedimentos e funções grandes sempre devem ser definidos
>   nos pacotes!

Um pacote é armazenado no DIANA no banco de dados, como um procedimento. Um pacote pode ser usado para quebrar a cadeia de dependência, no entanto, talvez fazendo isso desaparecer. É minha convicção que TODOS os códigos de produção (reais) devem estar em um pacote, nunca em um procedimento ou função independente.

> Referências
>
> [Ask Tom - PLS-123 error](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:571023051648)
>
> [Quem é diana e por que ela não permite que meus objetos de banco de
>   dados sejam compilados?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764656/who-is-diana-and-why-wont-she-let-my-database-objects-compile)
>
> [Limites do programa C PL/SQL 12c Realease 1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/limits.htm#LNPLS018)
>
> [Limites do programa PL/SQL 10g Realease 2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/limits.htm)